# How to use a List Item in fct_recode

Tags: r, tidyverse, forcats

I want to rename factor levels with fct_recode by using items I created beforehand.
I first create some labels and save them into a list:

```
#Creating the Labels:
LabelsWithN <- c(
  sprintf("Man(%s)", FreqGender["Man","Freq"]),
  sprintf("Woman(%s)", FreqGender["Woman","Freq"]),
  sprintf("Non-Binary(%s)", FreqGender["Non-Binary","Freq"]),
  sprintf("Other(%s)", FreqGender["Other","Freq"]),
  sprintf("Prefer Not To Disclose(%s)", FreqGender["Prefer not to disclose","Freq"])
)
```

This creates a chr list with items like "Man(105)", "Woman(51)" etc.
Now I want to relabel the factors in the original DataSet (i.e. "Man" --> "Man(105)") in order to label a graph. I want to use either the list item (i.e., LabelsWithN[1]) or directly the function creating the string (i.e., sprintf("Man(%s)", FreqGender["Man","Freq"]).

I then try to enter either the list item or the function into fct_recode:

```
#Using the Labels:
DataSet %>%
  mutate(`Gender. What_is_your_ge.._` = fct_recode(`Gender. What_is_your_ge.._`, LabelsWithN[1] = "Man", sprintf("Woman(%s)", FreqGender["Woman","Freq"]) = "Woman")) %>%
#THis is just the code for the graph:
  ggplot(aes(x = `Gender. What_is_your_ge.._` , y = `Age. How_old_are_you?`, main = "Age Distribution By Gender")) +
    geom_boxplot() +
    xlab("Gender (n)") +
    ylab("Age")
```

However, this yields:

```
"Unexpected '=' in:
"DataSet %>%
  mutate(`Gender. What_is_your_ge.._` = fct_recode(`Gender. What_is_your_ge.._`, LabelsWithN[1] ="
```

It doesn't matter if I use the function or the list item.

The vector is a factor and the list is filled with characters. If I manipulate the code to rename the factor "man" to "cat" ("cat" = "Man") the code works fine.

How can I address the list item/enter the function into fct_recode so that it works?
Also, can somebody explain to me what the problem here is? If I print out LabelsWithN[1] I get the correct string printed out.

Thank you and Bw,

Jan

Answer (score 1):

perhaps this might help ?

```
x <- factor(c("apple", "bear", "banana", "dear")) # what you want to recode
levels <- c(fruit = "apple", fruit = "banana") # how you want to recode it
x <- fct_recode(x, !!!levels) # recoding it
```